# Remember serial port permissions on app restart : PWA ( Kiosk Mode )

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, chromebook

I've this Progressive Web App and using it in Kiosk Mode on Chromebook. Is there any way I could remember serial port permissions on app restart? Since there's no session in Kiosk mode, no permission is preserved on reboot. Would appreciate any help.